# Avoid self intersection in Blender Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm currently working on a project and I'm spreading Flowers on a surface with geometry nodes, the problem is that there are sometimes multiple flowers overlapping, which looks awful. Is there a way to avoid self-intersection of instanced objects?

[image: Self-intersection of flowers]

Blend file:
[image]

Stay safe and have a great day ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this exact purpose Poisson distribution was invented - it randomized points guaranteeing no two points are closer than some distance $x$. So you can avoid overlap by switching *Distribute Points on Faces* node to **Poisson Disk** scattering method, and then setting the *Distance Min* to something like $0.2$ m:

[image]

If you want to scale the elements and still keep the minimum possible distance, you can distribute points first, and then move them closer together:

[image]

Perhaps a more reasonable setup for this kind of effect would be to spawn on half of a sphere and then flatten it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oki, thank you ^^
Worked out pretty well, it's not perfect because of the bend stems but it's definitely good enough.

Have a great day ^^