# Using Geometry Nodes to fill a mesh with instances that *do not* intersect each other

Tags: geometry-nodes

Without relying on physics sims is this possible? And how would it be done?

im basically trying to accomplish “a pile of random objects stuffed in a closet” kind of effect, essentially.  but procedurally. Making an infinite number of possible compositions possible.

Using an instance on points node from a collection of objects is obviously how it starts. And then filling the a volume with those objects.

The trick, though, arranging the objects randomly and in a way that keeps them from intersecting with each other. That part. How???

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279281/avoid-self-intersection-in-blender-geometry-nodes/279283#279283

Comment: In the example @JohnEason posted it is explained very precisely how this can be implemented with *Poisson Disk*. The method works as long as you are satisfied that a distance value is used in the distribution of the points. However, it is not a method that actually checks for intersection of geometry. This method does not exist for *Geometry Nodes*. For that you would have to use Physics.

Comment: i am pretty sure this is already now possible with geometry nodes with the help of raycast....but ...it would be super slow and not really usable because of that bad performance. So in the end...quellenform is right and you should use physics for that.